How to Export Full VBAProject in Excel
The question is how do we export a COMPLETE VBA project to text to allow detains to be retained in a version-management system, or to compare changes that have occurred between 'the' and 'now'.
My initial start was to use the code supplied by the stackoverflow question
How to Export VBAProject in Excel
That, while it provided the code base for source, missed various items (particularly the binary forms) and ither relevant details.
FYI, I have provided an answer below, which works, but required specific code to obtain each property of each object.  There must be a better way to collect these properties from the collection.

I'm a bit confused - you've posted one question and two follow on posts that look like they should be edits to your original question?  There's an Edit button just below the tags in  your question.

I got into strife once before because I posted a "solution" to a problem I had worked weeks upon solving WITHOUT initially posting it as a Question.
SO, this time, I created a question that I could post the solution to.  IE, I wanted the information to be available to others, so THEY didn't spend time trying to solve the same problem.
I would, though, LOVE for someone to resolve the question of how to step through the properties of an object and report the content.  I have done it the hard way by inquiring individually on the value of each property by name.

Maybe this is of any help

Try my free add-in: https://jkp-ads.com/download.asp#ExportVBAProject Alternatively, I also have this tool, which might be useful for systems like GitHub: https://jkp-ads.com/download.asp#GithubVBAExporter

Not sure that I'm game to add a binary from an unknown source.  Sorry.

@IanHicks I'd normally agree but Jan Karel has been around a while and his stuff generally works.  His FlexFind add-in has been a real life saver in finding those hidden links in workbooks.

Thanks @DarrenBartrup-Cook I appreciate the reassurance. The add-in's code is unprotected so you can first check it if needed.

While I think (hope) that it would be possible to access the object name collection directly, I was unable to identify a method that allowed me access without generating errors.  Hence, the attached code includes specific routines for each of the 'standard' objects to export the properties of that object.
If anyone knows how to do this, I would appreciate your changes...
Attribute VB_Name = "ModuleExportVBA"
Option Explicit
Const vbext_ct_ClassModule  As Long = 2
Const vbext_ct_Document     As Long = 100
Const vbext_ct_MSForm       As Long = 3
Const vbext_ct_StdModule    As Long = 1

Const isWriteErrors         As Boolean = False
Const isWriteAllErrors      As Boolean = False

Dim ExportFolder    As String
Dim iFile           As Integer
Dim sFormName       As String
Dim vPic            As Variant
'
'=================================================================================
'   To get the FORMS library, add (and then remove) a form.
'   It also needs IsNull0 (at the bottom),
'     and S4Sp (UnComment here)
Public Const S4Sp   As String = "    "
'
'=================================================================================

Public Sub ExportVBA()
Dim fs              As Object
Dim WBook           As Workbook
Dim VBComp          As Object
Dim frm             As MSForms.UserForm
Dim Sfx             As String
Dim i               As Long

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set WBook = ActiveWorkbook
    ExportFolder = WBook.Path & "\" & fs.GetBaseName(WBook.Name) & "\"
    If Not fs.FolderExists(ExportFolder) Then fs.CreateFolder (ExportFolder)
    Sfx = Dir(ExportFolder & "*.*")
    While Sfx <> vbNullString
        Call SetAttr(ExportFolder & Sfx, vbNormal)
        Sfx = Dir
    Wend

    If MsgBox("Delete export files from Folder?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1) = vbYes Then
        If Dir(ExportFolder & "*.cls") <> vbNullString Then Kill ExportFolder & "*.cls"
        If Dir(ExportFolder & "*.frm") <> vbNullString Then Kill ExportFolder & "*.frm"
        If Dir(ExportFolder & "*.frx") <> vbNullString Then Kill ExportFolder & "*.frx"
        If Dir(ExportFolder & "*.bas") <> vbNullString Then Kill ExportFolder & "*.bas"
        If Dir(ExportFolder & "*.frxs") <> vbNullString Then Kill ExportFolder & "*.frxs"
        If Dir(ExportFolder & "*.bmp") <> vbNullString Then Kill ExportFolder & "*.bmp"
        If Dir(ExportFolder & "a*.lis") <> vbNullString Then Kill ExportFolder & "a*.lis"
    End If

    For Each VBComp In WBook.VBProject.VBComponents
        Select Case VBComp.Type
            Case vbext_ct_ClassModule, vbext_ct_Document:
                Sfx = ".cls"
            Case vbext_ct_MSForm:
                Sfx = ".frm"
            Case vbext_ct_StdModule:
                Sfx = ".bas"
            Case Else:
                Sfx = vbNullString
        End Select
        If Not IsNull0(Sfx) Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Call SetAttr(ExportFolder & VBComp.Name & ".cls", vbNormal)
            Call SetAttr(ExportFolder & VBComp.Name & ".bas", vbNormal)
            Call SetAttr(ExportFolder & VBComp.Name & ".frm", vbNormal)
            Call SetAttr(ExportFolder & VBComp.Name & ".frx", vbNormal)
            Call SetAttr(ExportFolder & VBComp.Name & ".frxs", vbNormal)
            DoEvents
            Application.StatusBar = "Exporting " & VBComp.Name & Sfx: DoEvents
            Err.Clear
            DoEvents
            VBComp.Export ExportFolder & VBComp.Name & Sfx
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "Failed to export " & ExportFolder & VBComp.Name & Sfx & vbCrLf & _
                    Err.Number & ": = " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "From: " & Err.Source
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next

    iFile = FreeFile()
    Open ExportFolder & "ProjectReferences.txt" For Output As #iFile
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each VBComp In WBook.VBProject.References
        Print #iFile, "Description:" & vbTab & VBComp.Description
        Print #iFile, "Name:" & vbTab & VBComp.Name
        Print #iFile, "FullPath:" & vbTab & VBComp.FullPath
        Print #iFile, String(50, "=")
    Next
    Close #iFile

    Application.VBE.CommandBars("Menu Bar").Controls("View").Controls("Immediate Window").Execute
'    Application.VBE.CommandBars("Menu Bar").Controls("View").Controls("Watch Window").Execute
    With Application.VBE.Windows
        For i = 1 To .Count
            If InStr(.Item(i).Caption, " UserFormEquipment ") > 0 Then .Item(i).Visible = True
            If InStr(.Item(i).Caption, " UserFormzzzImages ") > 0 Then .Item(i).Visible = True
        Next
    End With
    For i = 1 To Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Count
        Set VBComp = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents(i)
        If VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_MSForm Then
            If Not VBComp.Designer Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print VBComp.Name & S4Sp & VBComp.Designer.Controls.Count
                Call exportMSForm(VBComp)
            Else
                Debug.Print VBComp.Name & "   Nothing"
                MsgBox "Due to a bug in Excel VBA, some UserForms do not export" & vbCrLf & _
                    " unless displayed in the Visual Basic IDE." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                    "Please display " & VBComp.Name & vbCrLf & _
                    "and try the Export again."
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Application.StatusBar = vbNullString
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

Private Sub exportMSForm(ByVal vbc As Object)
Dim i               As Long, j              As Long
Dim s               As String

    DoEvents
    iFile = FreeFile()
    Open ExportFolder & vbc.Name & ".frxs" For Output As #iFile
    On Error Resume Next
    DoEvents
    Call exportUserForm(vbc)
    Call exportMSFormControls(vbc)
    Close #iFile
    Set vbc = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub exportMSFormControls(vbc As Object)
Dim i               As Long, j              As Long, k              As Long
Dim s               As String
Dim vbo             As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each vbo In vbc.Designer.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(vbo)
            Case "CheckBox":        Call exportCheckBox(vbo)
            Case "ComboBox":        Call exportComboBox(vbo)
            Case "CommandButton":   Call exportCommandButton(vbo)
            Case "DTPicker":        Call exportDTPicker(vbo)
            Case "Frame":           Call exportFrame(vbo)
            Case "Image":           Call exportImage(vbo)
            Case "ImageCombo2":     Call exportImageCombo2(vbo)
            Case "Label":           Call exportLabel(vbo)
            Case "ListBox":         Call exportListBox(vbo)
            Case "MultiPage":       Call exportMultiPage(vbo)
            Case "OptionButton":    Call exportOptionButton(vbo)
            Case "ScrollBar":       Call exportScrollBar(vbo)
            Case "SpinButton":      Call exportSpinButton(vbo)
            Case "TabStrip":        Call exportTabStrip(vbo)
            Case "TextBox":         Call exportTextBox(vbo)
            Case "ToggleButton":    Call exportToggleButton(vbo)
            Case Else:              Call exportUnknown(vbo)
        End Select
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub exportUserForm(ByVal obj As Object)
Dim frm             As MSForms.UserForm
    On Error Resume Next
    Set frm = obj.Value.Object
    DoEvents
    Print #iFile, "Object " & obj.Name
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Parent.Name" & vbTab & obj.Property("Parent").Value.Item("Name")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Type" & vbTab & TypeName(obj)
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Name" & vbTab & obj.Name
    sFormName = obj.Name
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Height" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Height")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Left" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Left")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Top" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Top")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Width" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Width")

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Caption" & vbTab & obj.Properties.Item("Caption")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "InsideHeight" & vbTab & obj.Properties("InsideHeight")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "InsideWidth" & vbTab & obj.Properties("InsideWidth")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "StartUpPosition" & vbTab & obj.Properties("StartUpPosition")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ShowModal" & vbTab & obj.Properties("ShowModal")
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ActiveControl" & vbTab & obj.Properties("ActiveControl")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "BackColor" & vbTab & obj.Properties("BackColor")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "BorderColor" & vbTab & obj.Properties("BorderColor")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "BorderStyle" & vbTab & obj.Properties("BorderStyle")
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CanPaste" & vbTab & obj.Properties("CanPaste")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CanRedo" & vbTab & obj.Properties("CanRedo")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CanUndo" & vbTab & obj.Properties("CanUndo")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Controls.Count" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Controls").Value.Item("Count")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Cycle" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Cycle")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Name" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Font").Value.Item("Name")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Size" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Font").Value.Item("Size")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Charset" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Font").Value.Item("Charset")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Bold" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Font").Value.Item("Bold")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Italic" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Font").Value.Item("Italic")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Strikethrough" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Font").Value.Item("Strikethrough")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Underline" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Font").Value.Item("Underline")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Weight" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Font").Value.Item("Weight")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ForeColor" & vbTab & obj.Properties("ForeColor")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "KeepScrollBarsVisible" & vbTab & obj.Properties("KeepScrollBarsVisible")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MouseIcon.Type" & vbTab & obj.Properties("MouseIcon").Value.Item("Type")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MouseIcon.Height" & vbTab & obj.Properties("MouseIcon").Value.Item("Height")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MouseIcon.Width" & vbTab & obj.Properties("MouseIcon").Value.Item("Width")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MousePointer" & vbTab & obj.Properties("MousePointer")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "PictureAlignment" & vbTab & obj.Properties("PictureAlignment")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Picture.Type" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Picture").Value.Item("Type")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Picture.Height" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Picture").Value.Item("Height")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Picture.Width" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Picture").Value.Item("Width")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "PictureSizeMode" & vbTab & obj.Properties("PictureSizeMode")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "PictureTiling" & vbTab & obj.Properties("PictureTiling")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ScrollBars" & vbTab & obj.Properties("ScrollBars")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ScrollHeight" & vbTab & obj.Properties("ScrollHeight")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ScrollLeft" & vbTab & obj.Properties("ScrollLeft")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ScrollTop" & vbTab & obj.Properties("ScrollTop")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ScrollWidth" & vbTab & obj.Properties("ScrollWidth")
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Selected" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Selected")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "SpecialEffect" & vbTab & obj.Properties("SpecialEffect")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "VerticalScrollBarSide" & vbTab & obj.Properties("VerticalScrollBarSide")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Zoom" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Zoom")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "DesignMode" & vbTab & obj.Properties("DesignMode")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ShowToolbox" & vbTab & obj.Properties("ShowToolbox")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ShowGridDots" & vbTab & obj.Properties("ShowGridDots")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "SnapToGrid" & vbTab & obj.Properties("SnapToGrid")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "GridX" & vbTab & obj.Properties("GridX")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "GridY" & vbTab & obj.Properties("GridY")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "DrawBuffer" & vbTab & obj.Properties("DrawBuffer")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Enabled" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Enabled")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Tag" & vbTab & obj.Properties("Tag")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "HelpContextID" & vbTab & obj.Properties("HelpContextID")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "WhatsThisButton" & vbTab & obj.Properties("WhatsThisButton")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "WhatsThisHelp" & vbTab & obj.Properties("WhatsThisHelp")
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "RightToLeft" & vbTab & obj.Properties("RightToLeft")
    Print #iFile, "End Object"
    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Print #iFile, Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub exportCheckBox(obj As MSForms.CheckBox)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
End Sub

Private Sub exportComboBox(obj As MSForms.ComboBox)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "AutoTab" & vbTab & obj.AutoTab
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "AutoWordSelect" & vbTab & obj.AutoWordSelect
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "BoundColumn" & vbTab & obj.BoundColumn
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ColumnCount" & vbTab & obj.ColumnCount
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ColumnHeads" & vbTab & obj.ColumnHeads
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ColumnWidths" & vbTab & obj.ColumnWidths
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CurTargetX" & vbTab & obj.CurTargetX
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CurX" & vbTab & obj.CurX
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "DragBehavior" & vbTab & obj.DragBehavior
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "DropButtonStyle" & vbTab & obj.DropButtonStyle
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "EnterFieldBehavior" & vbTab & obj.EnterFieldBehavior
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "HideSelection" & vbTab & obj.HideSelection
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "LineCount" & vbTab & obj.LineCount
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ListCount" & vbTab & obj.ListCount
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ListIndex" & vbTab & obj.ListIndex
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ListRows" & vbTab & obj.ListRows
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ListStyle" & vbTab & obj.ListStyle
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ListWidth" & vbTab & obj.ListWidth
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MatchEntry" & vbTab & obj.MatchEntry
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MatchFound" & vbTab & obj.MatchFound
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MatchRequired" & vbTab & obj.MatchRequired
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MaxLength" & vbTab & obj.MaxLength
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "SelectionMargin" & vbTab & obj.SelectionMargin
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "SelLength" & vbTab & obj.SelLength
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "SelStart" & vbTab & obj.SelStart
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "SelText" & vbTab & obj.SelText
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ShowDropButtonWhen" & vbTab & obj.ShowDropButtonWhen
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TextColumn" & vbTab & obj.TextColumn
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TextLength" & vbTab & obj.TextLength
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TopIndex" & vbTab & obj.TopIndex

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub exportCommandButton(obj As MSForms.CommandButton)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TakeFocusOnClick" & vbTab & obj.TakeFocusOnClick

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub exportDTPicker(obj As Object)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CalendarBackColor" & vbTab & obj.CalendarBackColor
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CalendarForeColor" & vbTab & obj.CalendarForeColor
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CalendarTitleBackColor" & vbTab & obj.CalendarTitleBackColor
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CalendarTitleForeColor" & vbTab & obj.CalendarTitleForeColor
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CalendarTrailingForeColor" & vbTab & obj.CalendarTrailingForeColor
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CheckBox" & vbTab & obj.CheckBox
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CustomFormat" & vbTab & obj.CustomFormat
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Day" & vbTab & obj.Day
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "DayOfWeek" & vbTab & obj.DayOfWeek
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Format" & vbTab & obj.Format
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Hour" & vbTab & obj.Hour
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Hwnd" & vbTab & obj.Hwnd
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MaxDate" & vbTab & obj.MaxDate
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MinDate" & vbTab & obj.MinDate
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Minute" & vbTab & obj.Minute
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Month" & vbTab & obj.Month
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "OLEDropMode" & vbTab & obj.OLEDropMode
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Second" & vbTab & obj.Second
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "UpDown" & vbTab & obj.UpDown
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Year" & vbTab & obj.Year

    Print #iFile, "End Object"

    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub exportFrame(obj As MSForms.Frame)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ActiveControl" & vbTab & obj.ActiveControl
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CanRedo" & vbTab & obj.CanRedo
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CanUndo" & vbTab & obj.CanUndo
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Controls.Count" & vbTab & obj.Controls.Count
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Cycle" & vbTab & obj.Cycle
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "InsideHeight" & vbTab & obj.InsideHeight
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "InsideWidth" & vbTab & obj.InsideWidth
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "KeepScrollBarsVisible" & vbTab & obj.KeepScrollBarsVisible
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ScrollHeight" & vbTab & obj.ScrollHeight
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ScrollLeft" & vbTab & obj.ScrollLeft
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ScrollTop" & vbTab & obj.ScrollTop
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ScrollWidth" & vbTab & obj.ScrollWidth
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "VerticalScrollBarSide" & vbTab & obj.VerticalScrollBarSide
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Zoom" & vbTab & obj.Zoom

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub exportImage(obj As MSForms.Image)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
End Sub

Private Sub exportImageCombo2(obj As Object)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ComboItems.Count" & vbTab & obj.ComboItems.Count
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Hwnd" & vbTab & obj.Hwnd
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ImageList" & vbTab & obj.ImageList
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Indentation" & vbTab & obj.Indentation
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "OLEDragMode" & vbTab & obj.OLEDragMode
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "OLEDropMode" & vbTab & obj.OLEDropMode

    Print #iFile, "End Object"

    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub exportLabel(obj As MSForms.Label)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
End Sub

Private Sub exportListBox(obj As MSForms.ListBox)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "BoundColumn" & vbTab & obj.BoundColumn
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Column" & vbTab & obj.Column
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ColumnCount" & vbTab & obj.ColumnCount
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ColumnHeads" & vbTab & obj.ColumnHeads
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ColumnWidths" & vbTab & obj.ColumnWidths
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "IntegralHeight" & vbTab & obj.IntegralHeight
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ListCount" & vbTab & obj.ListCount
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ListIndex" & vbTab & obj.ListIndex
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ListStyle" & vbTab & obj.ListStyle
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MatchEntry" & vbTab & obj.MatchEntry
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MultiSelect" & vbTab & obj.MultiSelect
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TextColumn" & vbTab & obj.TextColumn
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TopIndex" & vbTab & obj.TopIndex
    Print #iFile, "End Object"
    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub exportMultiPage(obj As MSForms.MultiPage)
Dim i               As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MultiRow" & vbTab & obj.MultiRow
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Pages.Count" & vbTab & obj.Pages.Count
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TabFixedHeight" & vbTab & obj.TabFixedHeight
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TabFixedWidth" & vbTab & obj.TabFixedWidth
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TabOrientation" & vbTab & obj.TabOrientation

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
    For i = 0 To obj.Pages.Count - 1
        Call exportMultiPagePage(obj.Pages(i))
    Next

    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub exportMultiPagePage(obj As MSForms.Page)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ActiveControl" & vbTab & obj.ActiveControl
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CanRedo" & vbTab & obj.CanRedo
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CanUndo" & vbTab & obj.CanUndo
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Controls.Count" & vbTab & obj.Controls.Count
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Cycle" & vbTab & obj.Cycle
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "InsideHeight" & vbTab & obj.InsideHeight
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "InsideWidth" & vbTab & obj.InsideWidth
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "KeepScrollBarsVisible" & vbTab & obj.KeepScrollBarsVisible
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ScrollHeight" & vbTab & obj.ScrollHeight
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ScrollLeft" & vbTab & obj.ScrollLeft
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ScrollTop" & vbTab & obj.ScrollTop
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ScrollWidth" & vbTab & obj.ScrollWidth
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "VerticalScrollBarSide" & vbTab & obj.VerticalScrollBarSide
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Zoom" & vbTab & obj.Zoom

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub exportOptionButton(obj As MSForms.OptionButton)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
End Sub

Private Sub exportScrollBar(obj As MSForms.ScrollBar)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Delay" & vbTab & obj.Delay
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "LargeChange" & vbTab & obj.LargeChange
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Max" & vbTab & obj.Max
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Min" & vbTab & obj.Min
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Orientation" & vbTab & obj.Orientation
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ProportionalThumb" & vbTab & obj.ProportionalThumb
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "SmallChange" & vbTab & obj.SmallChange

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub exportSpinButton(obj As MSForms.SpinButton)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Delay" & vbTab & obj.Delay
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Max" & vbTab & obj.Max
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Min" & vbTab & obj.Min
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Orientation" & vbTab & obj.Orientation
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "SmallChange" & vbTab & obj.SmallChange

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub exportTabStrip(obj As MSForms.TabStrip)
Dim i               As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ClientHeight" & vbTab & obj.ClientHeight
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ClientLeft" & vbTab & obj.ClientLeft
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ClientTop" & vbTab & obj.ClientTop
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ClientWidth" & vbTab & obj.ClientWidth
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MultiRow" & vbTab & obj.MultiRow
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "SelectedItem" & vbTab & obj.SelectedItem
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TabFixedHeight" & vbTab & obj.TabFixedHeight
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TabFixedWidth" & vbTab & obj.TabFixedWidth
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TabOrientation" & vbTab & obj.TabOrientation
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Tabs.Count" & vbTab & obj.Tabs.Count

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
    For i = 0 To obj.Tabs.Count - 1
        Call exportTabStripTab(obj.Tabs(i), obj.Name)
    Next

    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Resume Next
End Sub


... Continued - ALL-UP, too many characters
FYI, S4SP is a standard constant in my 'Common' module,
as is the function IsNull0 (which overcomes the usual problem of testing for  in its various incarnations.
Private Sub exportTabStripTab(obj As MSForms.Tab, sParentName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Print #iFile, "Object " & obj.Name
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Parent.Name" & vbTab & sParentName
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Type" & vbTab & TypeName(obj)
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Name" & vbTab & obj.Name

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Accelerator" & vbTab & obj.Accelerator
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Caption" & vbTab & obj.Caption
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ControlTipText" & vbTab & obj.ControlTipText
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Enabled" & vbTab & obj.Enabled
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Index" & vbTab & obj.Index
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Tag" & vbTab & obj.Tag
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Visible" & vbTab & obj.Visible

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Print #iFile, Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub exportTextBox(obj As MSForms.TextBox)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "AutoTab" & vbTab & obj.AutoTab
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "AutoWordSelect" & vbTab & obj.AutoWordSelect
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CurLine" & vbTab & obj.CurLine
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CurTargetX" & vbTab & obj.CurTargetX
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CurX" & vbTab & obj.CurX
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "DragBehavior" & vbTab & obj.DragBehavior
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "EnterFieldBehavior" & vbTab & obj.EnterFieldBehavior
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "EnterKeyBehavior" & vbTab & obj.EnterKeyBehavior
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "HideSelection" & vbTab & obj.HideSelection
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "IntegralHeight" & vbTab & obj.IntegralHeight
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "LineCount" & vbTab & obj.LineCount
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MaxLength" & vbTab & obj.MaxLength
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MultiLine" & vbTab & obj.MultiLine
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "PasswordChar" & vbTab & obj.PasswordChar
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "SelectionMargin" & vbTab & obj.SelectionMargin
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "SelLength" & vbTab & obj.SelLength
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "SelStart" & vbTab & obj.SelStart
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "SelText" & vbTab & obj.SelText
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TabKeyBehavior" & vbTab & obj.TabKeyBehavior
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TextLength" & vbTab & obj.TextLength

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub exportToggleButton(obj As MSForms.ToggleButton)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
End Sub

Private Sub exportUnknown(obj As Object)
    On Error Resume Next
    Print #iFile, "Object UNKNOWN " & obj.Name
    Call exportCommonFields(obj)

    Print #iFile, "End Object"
End Sub

Private Function writeError() As Boolean
    writeError = isWriteErrors
    If Not writeError Then Exit Function
    If isWriteAllErrors Then Exit Function
    If Err.Number = -2147467259 Then writeError = False: Exit Function
    If Err.Number = -2147467261 Then writeError = False: Exit Function
    If Err.Number = -2147352573 Then writeError = False: Exit Function
End Function

Public Function RandomNameGenerate(Optional sPrefix As String = "zRnd") As String
Dim dtmNow          As Date
Dim dRandom         As Double
Dim iChar           As Long
    RandomNameGenerate = sPrefix
    dtmNow = Now()
    dRandom = CLng(CDbl(dtmNow - Int(dtmNow)) * 1000000)
    While dRandom > 0
        iChar = dRandom Mod 26
        RandomNameGenerate = RandomNameGenerate & Chr$(65 + iChar)
        dRandom = (dRandom - iChar) / 26
    Wend
    dRandom = CLng(CDbl(dtmNow) * 10000)
    While dRandom > 0
        iChar = dRandom Mod 26
        RandomNameGenerate = RandomNameGenerate & Chr$(65 + iChar)
        dRandom = (dRandom - iChar) / 26
    Wend
End Function

Private Sub exportCommonFields(obj As Object)
    On Error Resume Next
    Print #iFile, "Object " & obj.Name
    If TypeName(obj.Parent) = "Page" Then
        Print #iFile, vbTab & "Parent.Name" & vbTab & obj.Parent.Parent.Name & "." & obj.Parent.Name
    Else
        Print #iFile, vbTab & "Parent.Name" & vbTab & obj.Parent.Name
    End If
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Type" & vbTab & TypeName(obj)
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Name" & vbTab & obj.Name
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Height" & vbTab & obj.Height
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Left" & vbTab & obj.Left
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Top" & vbTab & obj.Top
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Width" & vbTab & obj.Width

    If isWriteErrors Then On Error GoTo StopIt
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "AutoSize" & vbTab & obj.AutoSize
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "BackColor" & vbTab & obj.BackColor
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "BackStyle" & vbTab & obj.BackStyle
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "BorderColor" & vbTab & obj.BorderColor
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "BorderStyle" & vbTab & obj.BorderStyle
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Cancel" & vbTab & obj.Cancel
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "CanPaste" & vbTab & obj.CanPaste
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ControlSource" & vbTab & obj.ControlSource
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ControlTipText" & vbTab & obj.ControlTipText
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Default" & vbTab & obj.Default
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Enabled" & vbTab & obj.Enabled
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Name" & vbTab & obj.Font.Name
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Size" & vbTab & obj.Font.Size
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Charset" & vbTab & obj.Font.Charset
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Bold" & vbTab & obj.Font.Bold
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Italic" & vbTab & obj.Font.Italic
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Strikethrough" & vbTab & obj.Font.Strikethrough
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Underline" & vbTab & obj.Font.Underline
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Font.Weight" & vbTab & obj.Font.Weight
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ForeColor" & vbTab & obj.ForeColor
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "HelpContextID" & vbTab & obj.HelpContextID
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "IMEMode" & vbTab & obj.IMEMode
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "LayoutEffect" & vbTab & obj.LayoutEffect
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Locked" & vbTab & obj.Locked
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MouseIcon.Type" & vbTab & obj.MouseIcon.Type
'    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MouseIcon.Handle" & vbTab & obj.MouseIcon.Handle
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MouseIcon.Height" & vbTab & obj.MouseIcon.Height
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MouseIcon.hPal" & vbTab & obj.MouseIcon.hPal
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MouseIcon.Width" & vbTab & obj.MouseIcon.Width
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Object" & vbTab & obj.Object
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "RowSource" & vbTab & obj.RowSource
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "RowSourceType" & vbTab & obj.RowSourceType
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "ScrollBars" & vbTab & obj.ScrollBars
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "SpecialEffect" & vbTab & obj.SpecialEffect
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TabIndex" & vbTab & obj.TabIndex
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TabStop" & vbTab & obj.TabStop
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Tag" & vbTab & obj.Tag
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Text" & vbTab & obj.Text
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TextAlign" & vbTab & obj.TextAlign
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Value" & vbTab & obj.Value
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Visible" & vbTab & obj.Visible
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "WordWrap" & vbTab & obj.WordWrap
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Accelerator" & vbTab & obj.Accelerator
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Caption" & vbTab & obj.Caption
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "MousePointer" & vbTab & obj.MousePointer

    vPic = vbNullString
    vPic = obj.Picture.Type
    If vPic <> vbNullString Then
        vPic = ExportFolder & sFormName & "." & IIf(TypeName(obj) = "Page", obj.Parent.Name & ".", vbNullString) & obj.Name & ".bmp"
        Print #iFile, vbTab & "Picture.Type" & vbTab & obj.Picture.Type
        Print #iFile, vbTab & "Picture.Height" & vbTab & obj.Picture.Height
        Print #iFile, vbTab & "Picture.Width" & vbTab & obj.Picture.Width
        If obj.Picture.Type > 0 Then
            Call SavePicture(obj.Picture, vPic)
            Print #iFile, vbTab & "PictureFile" & vbTab & vPic
        End If
    End If

    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Picture.hPal" & vbTab & obj.Picture.hPal
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "PicturePosition" & vbTab & obj.PicturePosition
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "PictureAlignment" & vbTab & obj.PictureAlignment
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "PictureSizeMode" & vbTab & obj.PictureSizeMode
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "PictureTiling" & vbTab & obj.PictureTiling
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Style" & vbTab & obj.Style
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "Alignment" & vbTab & obj.Alignment
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "GroupName" & vbTab & obj.GroupName
    Print #iFile, vbTab & "TripleState" & vbTab & obj.TripleState

    Exit Sub

StopIt:
    If Not writeError Then Resume Next
    Resume Next
End Sub

Public Function IsNull0(vValue As Variant) As Boolean
    IsNull0 = True
    On Error Resume Next
    If IsNull(vValue) Then Exit Function
    If vValue = vbNullString Then Exit Function
    If IsNumeric(vValue) Then If Val(vValue) = 0 Then Exit Function
    IsNull0 = False
End Function

